# "quote-props": "consistent" in .eslintrc in Atom

Tags: atom-editor, eslint

When using the Atom (v1.0.19) with packages linter (v1.9.1) and linter-eslint (v3.1.1), after every save of any `.js` file I get the following error:

> Configuration for rule "quote-props" is invalid: Value "consistent"
>   must be an enum value.

My `.eslintrc` contains (among others) `quote-props": [2, "consistent"]`, but when looking at http://eslint.org/docs/rules/quote-props#consistent, this seems like a valid config option.

So why the error, what am I doing wrong?

P.S. If I comment out the `quote-props` rule, everything works just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on `linter-eslint` package you are using eslint < 1.0.0 which doesn't support the `consistent` option.

You have to upgrade it to latest version of eslint. We are almost at `1.7.3` as per releases.

Based on docs for [linter-eslint](https://github.com/AtomLinter/linter-eslint#installation), you can actually install the latest version of eslint and then it will use that.

Comment: In the `linter-eslint` package in Atom I found the magic option "Use Global Eslint" and installed the newest eslint globally. Everything now works. Thanks!